# Mysql group joins same id together but still get duplicates

Tags: mysql

I would like to group `posts` with same id. Now i get duplicate of `posts` based on how many comments. Which is wrong, it should group and show the `latest comment` and not create row for each `comment`

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    myKey VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO users (name, myKey)
VALUES ("Gregor", "kx4ht"),
    ("Liza", "1lPxk"),
    ("Matt", "mP3fd"),
    ("Bob", "zStr5");
   
CREATE TABLE comments(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    post_id INT,
    comment VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO comments (post_id, comment)
VALUES (1, "Hello world"),
    (2, "I like iceCream"),
    (1, "I like unicorns");
   
CREATE TABLE post(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id INT,
    text VARCHAR(255),
    last_comment INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (`last_comment`) REFERENCES `comments` (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO post (user_id, text, last_comment)
VALUES (1, "My first post", 3),
    (1, "What is this?", 2);
```

Query:

```
SELECT u.name, p.text, c.comment
FROM post p
INNER JOIN users u ON (u.id = p.user_id)
INNER JOIN comments c ON (c.post_id = p.id)
WHERE (p.user_id = 1)
GROUP BY p.id, c.id;
```

Now

```
name    text    comment
Gregor  My first post   Hello world
Gregor  What is this?   I like iceCream
Gregor  My first post   I like unicorns
```

What i expect:

```
name    text    comment
Gregor  What is this?   I like iceCream
Gregor  My first post   I like unicorns
```

Comment: There's nothing in your code that makes it select only the latest comment in a post. Your query selects all the comments.

Comment: There's also no timestamp in the `comments` column, how would you determine the latest one?

Comment: The highest comment id for that post, is the latest comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your issue

```
SELECT u.name, p.text, c.comment
FROM post p
INNER JOIN users u ON (u.id = p.user_id)
INNER JOIN
(
            SELECT *
FROM comments c1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM  comments c2 
    WHERE c1.post_id = c2.post_id AND 
          c1.id < c2.id
)
) c ON (c.post_id = p.id)
WHERE (p.user_id = 1)
GROUP BY p.id, c.id;
```

Comment: I get this then: `
Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'db_183814748.c.comment' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Comment: @Printer Please review, I have my answer and tested this locally.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you